docker: selenium chrome driver setup
I've tried so many times to set up my docker with selenium and I please need your help.
My actual docker file is:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.11.4
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim AS base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.cache/pip to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to requirements.txt to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

#####################

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils

#download and install chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

#####################
# Set environment variables to prevent Firefox from using a display
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD ["python", "app.py"]

and my code is:
from selenium import webdriver
# import chromedriver_binary
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-audio")

# Configure o WebDriver para usar o Selenium Standalone Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

with a compose.yaml like this:
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"`

and finally my log:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "/app/app.py", line 15, in <module>
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |     driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |                   
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |          
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |    ^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py", line 40, in install
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |     driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |                  
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/manager.py", line 41, in _get_driver_binary_path
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |     binary_path = self._cache_manager.save_file_to_cache(driver, file)
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |                  
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |  ^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver_cache.py", line 53, in save_file_to_cache
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |     archive = self.save_archive_file(file, path)
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver_cache.py", line 46, in save_archive_file
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |     return self._file_manager.save_archive_file(file, path)
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |            ^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^^^^^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | ^^
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/file_manager.py", line 45, in save_archive_file
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |     
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "<frozen os>", line 215, in makedirs
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "<frozen os>", line 215, in makedirs
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "<frozen os>", line 215, in makedirs
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  |   File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
mercadolivrescraping-server-1  | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nonexistent'

I've tried install chrome and chrome driver manually and it didn't work, I've tried the chromedriver_binary lib from python with the chrome installed by the dockerfile and it didn't work and I've tried so many things and also didn't work.
Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong and what can I do instead, please? If you need any more information, please ask me.

Your app is trying to create a directory in the user's (appuser) home folder, which you have specified as /nonexistent in the adduser call in the Dockerfile.
I dont see any explicit creation of that folder in the Dockerfile, and I doubt the non-privileged user has permissions to create it at run time.
Try to do an explicit creation of user home folder prior to switching to the non-privileged user (USER appuser) in the Dockerfile.
For example: RUN mkdir -p /nonexistent && chown ${UID}:${UID} /nonexistent.
I recommend changing the name of the user home dir from /nonexistent to /home/appuser.
